# ¿Como puedo cambiar dinamicamente el label de un producto y a la vez borrar el contenido si ya existe alguno utilizando kivy y su spinner?

Tags: python-3.x, spinner, kivy

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner, SpinnerOption
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, RoundedRectangle
import sqlite3

Window.size = (250, 500 ) #Cambiamos el tamaño de la ventana para simular un celular

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class FirstWindow(Screen, FloatLayout):
   pass
    
    

class SecondWindow(Screen, Widget):
    data_items = ListProperty([])
    

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        r = self.get_products()
        self.construyespinner(r)
        


    def construyespinner(self, r):
        
        self.selectprod = Spinner(
         # default value shown
        text=str('Codigo'),
        # available values
        values= r, 
        # just for positioning in our example
        size_hint=(None, None),
        size=(50, 50),
        pos_hint={'center_x': .2, 'center_y': .7})
        self.add_widget(self.selectprod)

        self.selectprod.size = self.size
        self.selectprod.bind(text = self.recognizetext)
        self.selectprod.is_shortened = True

        #Construimos condicional para reiniciar el spinner
    

    def recognizetext(self, Spinner, r):
       
        r = self.get_products()
        d = Spinner.text
        
        
        #Cuando el spinner se abre cambiar el size 

       
        #Se recorre la lista en data list, 
        for codigo in r:
            if str(codigo) == d and self.Controlador ==False:
                print("Estoy seguro que comprobe su identidad")
                print(codigo)
                self.Contentquery(codigo)
            
            
               
        
                
                #Si el valor es igual al texto entonces
          


                #Pasamos a la funcion de dibujar precio y el input de las cantidades


        # if text = "GT-EL"
    
    def Borraprimero(self):
        return "Deberia estar borrando primero"        
    
    def Contentquery(self,valor):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("inventingt.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"""SELECT Descripcion, Preciolista FROM masterinv WHERE Codigo = "{(valor)}" """)
        r = cursor.fetchone()
        a, b = tuple(r)
        a = str(a)
        b = str(b)
        self.ConsPricDesc(a, b) 
    

    def ConsPricDesc(self, descripcion, plista):
        #Creamos el layout para estas etiquetas
        ContentBox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', pos = (150, 230))
        
        

        with self.canvas:
            Color(21/255,124,197,0.6, mode = 'rgba')
            descri = RoundedRectangle(size = (100,100))
            desclabel = Label(text = descripcion, halign='right', valign= 'middle', text_size =self.size)
            ContentBox.add_widget(desclabel)
                
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,0,0,.5, mode = 'rgba')
            prec = RoundedRectangle(pos= (50,50), size = (100,100))
            plistalab = Label(text = plista, pos_hint =({'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .7}), pos = (0,0), halign='right', valign= 'middle', text_size =self.size)
            ContentBox.add_widget(plistalab)
        
        return desclabel, plistalab
        
        

        

        




         
            
    
        
    def get_products(self):

        conn = sqlite3.connect("inventingt.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("""SELECT Codigo FROM masterinv """)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        r = [str(t[0]) for t in rows]
    
        return r


class WindowManager(ScreenManager, Widget):
    pass

class Buengiro(App):
    def build(self):
        #Inicializamos el screen manager para inicializar las paginas
        
        self.window = WindowManager()
        #add widgets to window
        
          
    
        
        #Agregamos el boton de inicializar la aplicacion

        #Conectamos una base de datos
        
        
        
        return self.window

    def animar_logo(self, *args):
        pass


    def prepararcotizador(self):
        pass

        #Llamar a la base de datos para recorrer el codigo de productos,
        # luego almacenar una lista en una variable.


        #Para cada producto en esa lista asignarle un numero en ascendente
        

    def controlador(self, numero):
        #Se recibe el input text

        #Se realiza el condicional para, si el numero es igual al string seleccionado [valor][descripcion] 

        #Dibuja el input de las cantidades para luego introducirla y luego calcular el total en la parte derecha.

        #Retornamos el valor sumado de cada iteracion

        pass

    def asignarNuevoProducto(self, numero):
        #Si el boton de cotizar es falso procede asignar una nueva fila 
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Buengiro().run()
```

> Deseo tener una label por defecto que pueda cambiar dinamicamente cuando ejecute un query en especifico, pero antes quiero borrar el contenido que ya se desplego en esa Label si ya lo realice anteriormente que cree en la función ConsPricDesc. Eso tomando en cuenta que tengo un spinner que puede desplegarse cada cuanto y seleccionar un campo en especifico, pero si hago eso, cada vez que ejecuto la funcion entonces dibujara una label y llenara esos campos por encima, entonces deseo que eso se borre primero para que el usuario por si se equivoca escoja otro producto.

> Ya intente desde el init de la clase FirstWindow definir unas labels con
> self.deslab = Label(text= ""), y despues tratar de llamarla desde la funcion ConsPricDesc() para que modifique dinamicamente el texto de una label base.
> **TOMAR POR FAVOR EN CUENTA SOLO LA CLASE FIRST WINDOW LO DEMAS NO IMPORTA, GRACIAS DE ANTEMANO**

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.